# Progress Bar Is Not Where It Should Be

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two Queries that I am stuck on. live view here http://codepen.io/riwakawebsitedesigns/pen/fvwGC/

**First Query**:
I have got this progress bar but I can not seem to get it at the bottom under my  image It is the css.

**Second Query**:
On my Javascript I would like the images to slide left how do I do that at the moment it fades with the progress-bar

```
code for first query

.slideshow {
  position:relative;
}

.slideshow-inner {
  position:relative;
}

.slideshow-inner img {
  position:absolute;
}

.progress-bar {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#383838 0%, #505050 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#383838 0%, #505050 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#383838 0%, #505050 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#383838 0%, #505050 100%); 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 20px;
  position:relative;
  width: 0%;
}
```

Code For Second Query

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var currentIndex = 0;
  function progress() {
    $(".slideshow img").hide();
    $(".slideshow img").eq(currentIndex).show();
    $(".progress-bar").css("width", "0");

    currentIndex++;
    if (currentIndex > 2) {
    currentIndex = 0;
    }

    $('.slideshow-bar').animate({
      width: '100%'
    }, 5000, "linear", progress);
  }
  progress();
</script>
```

Code HTML

```
<div class="page-wrapper">
  <div class="slideshow">
    <div class="slideshow-inner">
      <img data-src="holder.js/100%x280/grey" >
    </div>
    <div class="slideshow-inner">
      <img data-src="holder.js/100%x280/sky">
    </div>
    <div class="slideshow-inner">
      <img data-src="holder.js/100%x280/vine">
    </div>
    <div class="slideshow-inner">
      <img data-src="holder.js/100%x280/lava">
    </div>
    <div class="progress-bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're going to need to provide a jsfiddle for this.

Comment: @Liam Ok Will post codepen/fiddle in next five min

Comment: you're missing a dot `.slideshow`

Comment: Y U NO jsfiddle!! :) everybody having questions relying on HTML + CSS + JS should post a question with an attached JSFiddle to it - some of them are to trivial to do it but still - it will save the time of a people trying to help! :)

Comment: codepen/fiddle here http://codepen.io/riwakawebsitedesigns/pen/fvwGC/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First problem:** By using `position:absolute` for the images, you are removing them from the document flow and causing the progress bar to be at the top (because the images are no longer there to push it down). To fix, just change `position:absolute` to `position:relative` (or even get rid of `position` altogether there).

**Second problem:** You will need to restructure your HTML to have a "container" which is wider than the actual display area. The display area will use `overflow:hidden` to clip it. Then, animate the "viewport" you have created.

Comment: Still working on the second query I don't know how to add it to the animate view port got first query fixed cheers

Comment: Tried to added it to js but not sliding left the image